# How to setting footer in docx using python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have trouble to setting footer in Docx using `python-docx`.

I have code like this :

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
section = document.sections[0]
footer = section.footer
footer.add_paragraph("This is page number")
footer.footer_distance = Cm(3)
footer.bottom_margin = Cm(5.0)
footer.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT

document.save('mydoc.docx')
```

I'm setting the footer with `bottom = Cm(5.0)`, `footer_distance = Cm(3)`, alignment `RIGHT`. But nothing happens.

Can somebody help me? Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Did you Check this: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html

Comment: Yeah, dave. But I didn't get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A footer object has no `.footer_distance` or `.bottom_margin` property. Those are on the section.
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section.footer_distance

If you change your code to:

```
section.footer_distance = Cm(3)
```

You should see that spacing change in the document.

Comment: So, is there a way to make ```footer.add_paragraph("This is page number")```  up?

Comment: A footer is a content container just like the body is, so you use `footer.paragraphs` and `footer.add_paragraph()` in the same ways.